# Delphi: CoolTrayIcon's ShowBalloonHint is not working

Tags: delphi, show, system-tray, balloon

I used CoolTrayIcon, and ShowBalloonHint to warn user to incoming messages.
Everything has been working fine till today.

Today once I saw the Balloon, but later never. In these period some Windows update installed in the background as I think - later the system showed a "Restart" dialog.

I tried to set all properties, and to make a new test project and to copy my old code. Nothing worked.

Last chance I tried the CoolTrayIcon's demo.
And it is also is not working for me!!!

The environment is:

> Win7/x64, Delphi 6 professional (with updates), 4.4.4 CoolTrayIcon (last).

So here is the question:
Do you experienced same anomaly? May this caused the SP?
Or what?

I don't know how to determine that is this problem a System Failure (local), or caused Windows 7 update (then it is global, appearing everywhere)...

Comment: I don't see where you tried using the debugger. Use it to find out where your program fails.

Comment: Hi! The program don't fails, the ModifyIcon got true result. I rebooted 3 times... I must change to other icon, or build my own balloon... :-)

Comment: Have you tried reporting this to the author?

Comment: The email address isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CoolTrayIcon is a bit outdated.

Try with TJvTrayIcon from [JEDI Visual Component Library](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/).

TJvTrayIcon shows balloon hints on Windows 7.

Comment: So, are you conclusively saying that the component doesn't work on modern operating systems anymore, or are you just suggesting an alternative without actually answering the question that was asked?

Comment: @RobKennedy, I've already experiencied this problem with CoolTrayIcon, imho is a great control but it doesn't show balloon hints (notifications) on Windows 7, I don't know why. I just only suggested a good replacement.

Comment: Now just one job have for me - to complile JEDI without crash my computer - as in all time - see my same question about it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found some information that might be handy on this case:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hennings/archive/2010/01/08/delphi-notifyicondata-and-windows7.aspx

Basically:

> The problem lies in the NOTIFYICONDATA Structure
>
> The member guidItem must no longer be 0 (zero) on Windows 7, but must
>   contain the GUID of the icon that the notifier is associated with.

Hope it helps someone.